# Name the variable as value of another variable in c#

Tags: c#

I want to give name to a variable as value of another variable in C#.
for example i have a variable as:

```
string abc = "drawCircle";
```

I want a variable whose name should be "drawCircle". Is it event possible in C#?

Comment: You probably want to refer to a variable indirectly by its name? Consider using a dictionary.

Comment: You can use an enumeration.

Comment: what will you do with `abc`?

Comment: Possible. Yes. But why?

Comment: Depending on your scenario, a possible solution would be to use template engine like T4 to generate your own code.

Comment: Can anybody explain to me that why this question has been down voted??

Answer (score 0):

Yup you can achieve this in C# with many ways here is one example using Dicitonary.

```
            string abc = "drawCircle";

            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =
                new Dictionary<string, string>();

            dictionary.Add(abc, "drawCircleValue");
            //dictionary["drawCircle"]
            Console.WriteLine(dictionary[abc]); 
            Console.ReadLine();
```

for more information see this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks!.

Comment: I think this one is the best way to achieve your goal. The other way could be using reflection.